# How to get the sum of values with the same value in another column with Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a csa file with dates in one column and respective temperature in another column. I want to have the average temperature of each day only for the dates 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 and 30.

This is what I have for now but I am not able to put the first values in each day.

```
days_needed = [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
dailytemp = []

for i in range (count_row): 
    if df.Year[i] == '2000':
        if (int(df.Day[i]) in days_needed):
            if(int(df.Day[i]) == int(df.Day[i-1])):
                num += float(df.Lufttemperatur[i])
                print(num)

            dailytemp.append(float(num/8)) #8 because I have 8 temp values in each day
    num = 0
        

print(dailytemp)
```

The dataframe looks like this:
..

2000-04-24,,12.1,G,,

2000-04-24,,12.6,G,,

2000-04-24,,12.2,G,,

2000-04-24,,11.2,G,,

2000-04-24,,10.7,G,,

2000-04-25,,10.1,G,,

2000-04-25,,8.8,G,,

2000-04-25,,6.8,G,,

2000-04-25,,8.8,G,,

2000-04-25,,9.5,G,,

2000-04-25,,12.3,G,,

2000-04-25,,7.2,G,,

2000-04-25,,6.2,G,,

2000-04-26,,5.3,G,,

2000-04-26,,4.8,G,,

2000-04-26,,9.1,G,,
.
.

and expected output should be the value of (10.1+8.8+ .. +6.2)/8

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong and help me solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share a sample dataframe and expected output?

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[(df['Year'] == '2000') & df['Day'].isin(days_needed)
      ].groupby('Day').Lufttemperatur.mean()
```

You probably also need to either filter or group by month as well, but it wasn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the date column as 'A' and value column as 'B', below is the simplest way to get the average day wise.

*Assumption: Date column is as mentioned and is not a datetime column*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":['25-10-2020','25-10-2020','25-10-2020','25-10-2020','25-10-2020','25-10-2020', '24-10-2020','24-10-2020', '24-10-2020', '24-10-2020'],"B":[12.1, 13.1,10, 12, 8,10,11,12,13,13]})
df.A=pd.to_datetime(df.A)
days_needed=[24,25,26]
df['Year']=df.A.dt.year
df['Day']=df.A.dt.day
grouped_df=df.loc[(df['Year'] == 2020) & df['Day'].isin(days_needed)].groupby('Day', as_index=False).agg({"B":np.mean})
```

**Sample Output**

```
       A          B
0  24-10-2020  12.250000
1  25-10-2020  10.866667
```

**Edit 1**: Added Filter as suggested by @Marat with a few changes in existing code.

Comment: protip: `groupby` accepts `as_index` argument, which will eliminate the last line: `df.groupby('A', as_index=False)`

Comment: Edited the same based on your comments and answer. It's really a good way @Marat

Comment: another protip: to extract year (day, month) from a datetime column, you can simply use `df['A'].dt.year`. Or, even avoid converting to datetime at all: `df['A'].str[-4:]`

Comment: You may need to change column 'B'  to 'Lufttemperatur' before running this code